# Angular directive not working with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created an Angular directive but it won't run with `ng-repeat`. I don't know why.
The second directive runs successfully.

**JavaScript:**

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
                .controller('Ctrl',['$scope', function ($scope) {
                    $scope.vvv = [];
                    $scope.bbb = [];
                    $scope.testdatas = [{text : 0},{text : 1},{text : 2},{text : 3}]
                }])
                .directive('wstCheckbox', function () {
                    return {
                        restrict:'EA',
                        replace:true,
                        template:'<div ng-transclude></div>',
                        scope:{
                            modelname : '=' //ths is the model
                        },
                        transclude:true,
                        link : function (scope,element,attrs) {
                            console.log(element)
                            $(element).find('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
                                scope.modelname = [];
                                scope.$apply(function () {
                                    $(element).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
                                        scope.modelname.push($(this).val());
                                    })
                                })

                            })
                        }
                    }
                })
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <wst-checkbox modelname="vvv">
        <div>{{vvv}}</div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="data.text" ng-repeat="data in testdatas"/>
    </wst-checkbox>
    <wst-checkbox modelname="bbb">
        <div>{{bbb}}</div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="0" id="4"/><label for="4">index 0</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="1" id="5"/><label for="5">index 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="2" id="6"/><label for="6">index 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" value="3" id="7"/><label for="7">index 3</label>
    </wst-checkbox>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackOverflow. Please restructure your code sample for better readability, strip it down to the most relevant part and make sure your posting includes a clear question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that at the point you are binding to the change event, angular has not rendered the ng-repeat yet. If you put a timeout to give it time to render everything it should work.

Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZckzAm3MP9rBcCp2CP6F?p=preview)

```
link : function (scope,element,attrs) {
  console.log(element)
  $timeout(function(){
    $(element).find('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function () {
      scope.modelname = [];
      scope.$apply(function () {
        $(element).find('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function () {
          scope.modelname.push($(this).val());
        })
      })
    })

  },0);

}
```

I would recommend you to use ng-change and ng-model in your input and do everything in a more Angular way. You should be aware of that scope in directives using  transclude may work the way you would expect.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you recommend some site that have angular demo? TKS again!

Comment: Dont forget to inject $timeout to your controller like this: 
.controller('Ctrl',['$scope','$timeout', function ($scope,$timeout)

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code in Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Vh4KxPxJyEsaOPrK38sV?p=preview and I didn't see any issue except that you need to set `value="{{data.text}}"` instead of `value="data.text"` I added a span an a label to make the first directive look like the second one.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Can you share you code about it? I can't make it work as your method